# When running the code, I want a window to pop up and not a console(Python)

Tags: python, window, exe

When running the code, I want a window to pop up and not a console. Who can help me?

My Code

```py
import pyautogui
import time

msg = input("Enter the message: ")
n = input("How many times ?: ")

print("Dein Spaß beginnt in...")

count = 7
while(count != 0):
    print(count)
    time.sleep(1)
    count -= 1

print("Fire in the hole!!!")

for i in range(0,int(n)):
    pyautogui.typewrite(msg + '\n')
```

Comment: If you have no console, what do you expect: `msg = input("Enter the message: ")` to do?

Comment: doesn't your console appear in a window?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand the easiest way around this issue to get a pop-up is to rather make a tkinter widget.

Please find some documentation on this here:

[https://coderslegacy.com/python/list-of-tkinter-widgets/#:~:text=%20Python%20Tkinter%20Widgets%3A%20%201%20Frame%3A.%20Outlines,the%20user%20interface.%20A%20simple%20box...%20More%20](https://coderslegacy.com/python/list-of-tkinter-widgets/#:%7E:text=%20Python%20Tkinter%20Widgets%3A%20%201%20Frame%3A.%20Outlines,the%20user%20interface.%20A%20simple%20box...%20More%20)

This is just one of many references.

I hope and trust that this can help. It will be more to code, but I think you can have more versatility and space on expansion from the base upwards, once working.